# JavaScript/JQuery - get src from Video Tag when it starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i need your help.
I'm developing an Webbrowser App and in the App i want to play Videos from a Website in a Media Element.

So i need the Source. The Problem is that some Pages write the Source in the src="" only after starting the Video.

So I need a methode that gives me the src when the Video starts.

I hope you understand me.

Sorry for my bad English.

By

Comment: `some Pages write the Source in the src="" only after starting the Video` that's a very generic statement. Can you add any of your current code that has the issue whereby the `src` is not always obtainable? If possible please add a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.com) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I find only one Sample. http://streamcloud.eu/maubisu0oujm/the.simpsons.2501.hdtv-lol.mp4.html Please ignore the ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a listener that listens for the `play` event:

```
document.getElementById('yourvideoid').addEventListener('play', function() {
    console.log(this.src);
});
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('#yourvideoid').on('play', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

If your video does not have an id or class you could do something like:

```
$('video').on('play', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: But if the Video Element has no Id or Class?

Comment: Hello anyone there? Can someone else help me?